# Working on a microsoft access project. I get the error "Query must have one destination field" when I try to open a form

Tags: database, ms-access

I've never worked with access before and I'm trying to make a change in a form. But when I try to open it, a window will appear saying "Query must have at least one destination field". I don't really know what that means or how to fix it

[image: da]

Comment: Can you open the query with a right-click? Maybe it is missing some fields/placeholders?

Comment: no it just does the same thing